# ajax request to codeigniter controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am making an ajax request from my codeigniter view in javascript function but nothing happens and the success alert (ok) pops up

```
function show_drop_downn(){
    document.getElementById("drop_downn").style.visibility = "visible"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ok/index.php/search/ajax_delete_ntify",
        success: alert('ok'),
    }); 
}
```

This is my controller it is working perfect, when i copy paste the url (used in ajax request) in my browser every thing goes good, controller makes a call to the model and it works perfect

```
function ajax_delete_ntify()
{
    echo "incontroller";
    $email=$this->session->userdata('email_of_user');
    $this->load->model('search_peoplee');
    $data['userid']= $this->search_peoplee->get_userid_from_email($email);
    foreach ($data['userid'] as $row)
    {
        $one=$row->userid;
    }
    $this->search_peoplee->delete_notifications($one);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Also, check your consoles Network tab and verify the request is going thru.

Comment: actually i am implementing a notification method, when user hovers over a flag all the notifications are shown and are deleted

Comment: You need to pass `success` a function.  In your case you are running `alert('ok')` and passing `success` the return value of `alert` (which is `undefined`).  You need to do `success: function(){ alert('ok'); }`

Comment: What do you expect to happen after your AJAX call?  Just running an AJAX call isn't going to display the contents of the URL on your page.  You need to do that yourself.

Comment: ajax gives a call to controller and that controller gives a call to model which is programmed to delete a row from a table in database but that never happens, i have made it sure that my controller and model work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

View :

```
function show_drop_downn(){
    document.getElementById("drop_downn").style.visibility = "visible"; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/ok/index.php/search/ajax_delete_ntify",
        success:function(
         console.log("success");
        )
    }); 
}
```

Controller :

```
function ajax_delete_ntify()
{
    echo "incontroller";
    $email=$this->session->userdata('email_of_user');
    $this->load->model('search_peoplee');
    $data= $this->search_peoplee->get_userid_from_email($email);
    $res=$this->search_peoplee->delete_notifications($data[0]->userid);
    if($res){
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
    }else{
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>false));
    }
}
```